# Style select button like bootstrap 2.3 instead of chosen.js

Tags: bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

In the administrator backend of Joomla each select box is automatically styled with the Chosen.js plugin. But some buttons are styled with Bootstrap. Is there a way that I can make the Select element look like a bootstrap dropdown?

Why do I need this? For example in the article edit more there are several button at the bottom (like 'Article', 'Image' 'Page Break', and 'Read More'). I use a plugin that added a select button next to those buttons and the heigth of the chosen button is significantly lower than that of the bootstrap buttons. See this image:

[image]

I would like to have this dropdown look more like the other button next to it. Since the code only adds a `select` element and chosen.js generates additional dom elements from that I don't know how I can adjust that style without affecting every other select element on the page.

I am curious if there is an easy solution, or is this maybe a known problem of Joomla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to open the following file:

> plugins/editors/switcher/switcher.php

Then go to line **180**, where you'll see this:

```
. '<div id="switcherSelector" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0 0 0 5px;display:inline-block;"><input type="hidden" id="editorswitcher-currentvalue" value="'
```

which you need to replace with this:

```
. '<div id="switcherSelector" class="btn-toolbar"><input type="hidden" id="editorswitcher-currentvalue" value="'
```

---

Then online **190**, you will see the following:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Directly below this, add the following code:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration('
    #switcherSelector { display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; }
    #switcherSelector .chzn-container-single .chzn-single { height: 26px; line-height: 26px; }
    #switcherSelector .chzn-container-single .chzn-single div { top: 2px; }
');
```

---

### Result:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: A very nice solution, works exactly like I expected.

Comment: @lanoxx - Glad it helped

Comment: I published the changes at `https://github.com/lanoxx/editorswitcher`. It would be nice if this could make it back to the original upstream source but I am not sure how to contact the original author. In the mean anyone interested can use my repository.

Comment: @lanoxx - If the original author can't be contacted via their website. Keep the repository. I'll probably add some PR's as it's using old deprecated code

Comment: I left a comment on his website, lets see if he contacts me. You are welcome to send me pull requests on github.